# LINE PATTERN FILL for plygon symbology in qgis 2.18 by pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology

i would like to create this symbology from this vector layer.[image]

by taking advatage of pyqgis and programming. i try to develope a code but i got stock , can somebody help me?
layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\ost\Desktop\ASPERG_TEST/eigentum_der_gemeinde.shp','test', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])

symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(symbol)
symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2.create('color':'red', 'style': 'f_diagonal')
renderer.symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/343616/edit) the question to include the actual code used and not just a screenshot?

Comment: You should also specify which version of QGIS you are using. The code in your screenshot is 2.X API.